# How to calculate the series of this function?

Tags: series-expansion

I have to calculate the series of the function

```
F[r_] := 1 - a - a*r^(5 + n)/(r^(8 + n) + 1);
```

for `r->Infinity` for generic integer `n>0`. The naive:

```
Series[F[r],{r,Infinity,20},Assumptions->{n>0}]
```

gives the input as a result

Comment: 1 - a + a*Sum[(-1)^(j + 1)/r^(n + 5 + j*(n + 8)), {j, 1, Infinity}]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `Series` cannot perform power series expansions where the order of terms in the series will depend on a symbolic parameter.  In your case, the terms which appear in your power series will depend on $n$.

Comment: This said, if you plug in a few different values of $n$, a pretty clear pattern emerges.

Comment: `Maple` can perform power series expansions.